# function returning pointer vs function returning array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

func1 is giving warning & junk value while func2 is giving the right output. What's the difference between the two?

```
//func 1
unsigned char *CreateData()
{
unsigned char data[]="Thanks";
return data;
}

/* func 2
unsigned char *CreateData()
{
unsigned char *data=malloc(6);
strncpy(data,"Thanks",strlen("Thanks"));
return data;
}


int main()
{
unsigned char *a;
a=CreateData();
printf("%s",a);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: In func1 you are creating a variable called data o nthe stack and it is destroyed when the function returns.  You may NOT return pointers or arrays from a function if you create them on the stack - you HAVE to use malloc.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks. And malloc takes memory from heap. Therefore that persists for the entire program. right?

Comment: Until the program ends or you call free for the pointer.

Comment: You're buffer overflowing here. "Thanks" is 6 characters long, but C-style strings are null-terminated meaning the null character is being written somewhere outside the memory you allocated for it.

Comment: @GriffinG: No, the null character isn't being written at all, because the code uses `strncpy()` rather than `strcpy()`. [See my rant on `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: I didn't even notice that, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the first implementation of `CreateData`, you return a pointer to a variable with automatic storage duration and then use it past its lifetime, which is undefined behavior.

Less formally, what's actually happening is that `data` is allocated on the stack, and once you get around to using it as `a`, `CreateData` has ended and that stack space is now available for other functions to use, like `main` or `printf`, and those other functions are trampling over the space that was previously reserved for `data`.

When you use `malloc`, though, the memory is said to be allocated on the heap, not on the stack, and memory on the heap is only released when *you* tell it to be released (using `free`). Unlike with variables with automatic storage duration, the memory will not be released when `CreateData` has returned, so you can continue to use that memory in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The static array ( `ex. unsigned char data[]="Thanks";` ) will be destroyed as soon as you leave the current stack frame (basically, when the function you're in returns).

The dynamic array ( `ex. unsigned char *data=malloc(6);` ) sticks around forever until you [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it. It's lives on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Function 1 returns a pointer to the local variable (allocated on stack). This is an undefined behaviour.

In Function 2, the data block is allocated on the heap, hence its value persists out of the scope of the function.